# NSXMLParser fails with NSXMLParserErrorDomain error 111; error 111 isn't defined?

Tags: ios, xml, nsxmlparser

A few people seem to have run into NSXMLParser error 111 before, but it's not defined in the constants.  This answer seems to have mistaken 111 with 11: [NSXMLParserErrorDomain 111](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20454853/nsxmlparsererrordomain-111)

As far as I can tell, I have no illegal characters in my final xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?><wsse:BinarySecurityToken wsu:Id="uuid:383b6148-1c27-45ab-963b-30e14af8154e" ValueType="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2009/11/swt-token-profile-1.0" EncodingType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">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</wsse:BinarySecurityToken>
```

I've also tried changing the encoding to utf-8, but it made no difference.  What causes a parser to fail with error 111?  Is the parser not set up correctly, or is the XML killing it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I was simply passing in an entirely wrong string.  The XML chunk came from a larger JSON structure, which I then processed down to get the only XML part; yet when inited the parser, I used the wrong string to create the NSData.  So make sure you aren't mixing variables up.  I'm still not sure why error 111 isn't defined in the documentation, though.

Answer (score 1):

In NSXMLParserError docs, it says:

```
The following error codes are defined by NSXMLParser. For error codes not listed here, see the <libxml/xmlerror.h> header file.
```

The number 111 isn't mentioned in this list, so we go to `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.11.sdk/usr/include/libxml2/libxml/xmlerror.h`, and find the value:

```
XML_ERR_USER_STOP, /* 111 */
```

There isn't a lot of documentation on XML_ERR_USER_STOP in libxml2, but from reading the changeset, it looks like it's a fast-fail when the parser sees an unexpected EOF.

Referred DebugCN and Internet.